# GAE: django-nonrel: No module named myapp.views

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm using django-nonrel on google app engine.

I've got this problem when visiting http://localhost:8080/album

```
Could not import myapp.views. Error was: No module named myapp.views
```

my urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^_ah/warmup$', 'djangoappengine.views.warmup'),
    ('^$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', {'template': 'home.html'}),
    (r'^album/$', 'myapp.views.view_albums'),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

my views:

```
def view_albums(request):
    return direct_to_template(request, 'album.html', locals())
```

Part of Settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    #    'django.contrib.sites',
    'djangotoolbox',

    # djangoappengine should come last, so it can override a few manage.py commands
    'djangoappengine',
)
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media/')
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
```

I'm not using django's site framework, the app structure is

```
myapp
  -\dbindexer
  -\django
  -\djangoappengine
  -\djangotoolbox
  -\media
  -\templates
  -__init__.py
  -app.yaml
  -views.py
  -urls.py
  -settings.py
  -models.py
  -manage.py
  -cron.yaml
  -dbindexes.py
...
```

Comment: Have you tried just `views.view_albums`? 'myapp' doesn't look like it's part of your namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using

from myapp.views import * in urlconf

please try 
-- in urlconf

from views import *